# Is there a way to ensure gc when using opencvsharp in a .NET env?

Tags: c#, opencv, garbage-collection

I am using opencvsharp to do some image processing in a windows forms app and am having problems ensuring that the GC can collect at the appropriate times. This is causing an exception at the point when I run out of process memory. I sort of fixed this by following various recommendations (put all open cv iDisposables in using blocks, avoid unneeded allocations etc) but when I moved on to batch processing I still ran out of memory after a number of images.

Following some advice on an opencv forum, I put my code in a try..catch...finally sequence, expecting the GC.Collect() to sort out the problem.

```
        private void procDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && Directory.Exists(_srcFolder))
            {

                _dstFolder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_srcFolder);
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (Path.GetExtension(files[i]).ToLower() == ".jpg" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(files[i]).ToLower() == ".png" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(files[i]).ToLower() == ".gif" ||
                            Path.GetExtension(files[i]).ToLower() == ".bmp")
                        {
                            //process and save new files with 'converted ' tag in file name
                            using (Mat currentImage = ConformInputImage(Cv2.ImRead(files[i], ImreadModes.Color)))
                            {
                                using (_convMatBGR = ConvertImage(_srcMatBGR, currentImage))
                                {
                                    string outFileName = Path.Combine(_dstFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(files[i])) + "_conv" + Path.GetExtension(files[i]).ToLower();
                                    _convMatBGR.ImWrite(outFileName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        i--;
                    }
                    finally { GC.Collect(); }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, it still hits the exception but now I can tell it to carry on, which it does quite happily for any number of images. This produces the memory usage shown here:

[image: image of 4BG memory being used]

Each step on the ramp is a new image being processed until it hits the exception, at which point it clears up all the garbage and when I dismiss the message box, it carries on. The garbage does seem to be collected but without freeing up any memory until the exception is reached - how do I fix it so it never hits the exception?n

Comment: are you running in 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the image, memory gets up to almost 4GBytes

Comment: "almost 4Gb" does not say much, since that is within the 32bit limit, assuming you have the physical RAM, the memory usage should exceed 4Gb before throwing any OOM exceptions.

Comment: 2GBytes on a windows system.

Comment: That depends, there are ways to use 4Gb on windows. I'm not sure that is *actually* used, but I for sure would check the actual bitness it runs in, instead of trusting some memory usage graph.

Comment: So what are the objects on your heap? You literally have the memory delta report created, but don't show anything of use (the report I mentioned, your architecture, what temporary images those functions you're calling use, cause I'm sure you're creating a whole bunch, etc).

Comment: I can certainly do that but it leaves my problem unsolved as it will still only take a few hundred images to hit the memory limit whereas I want o process thousands.

Comment: @JonasH You were right - I was running in default 'Any CPU' mode. Switching to x64 sees the app running up a memory bill of >32G before it hits problems. Now looking at comments from Blindy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases you should not need to call `GC.Collect` manually. It will run automatically before running out of memory. If you are running into out of memory exceptions it is likely that you have a memory leak. If the memory usage goes down after an exception it is likely that the exception caused some reference to be released, and *that* allows the GC to collect the memory.

I would start by:

1. Check if the result of `Cv2.ImRead` needs to be disposed. I.e. is `ConformInputImage` documented to dispose its input when the result object is disposed?
2. Take a memory snapshot and check the object table. I would expect there to be only one or two `Mat` objects alive at any point. If there is any more than that you have found your leak.
3. Take two memory snapshots and compare them, is there any type of object that increase in count between the two snapshots? That is a likely candidate for a leak.

Note that you might need to be more vigilant with disposing objects when dealing with native libraries. Any managed wrapper should implement a finalizer to ensure the native objects are eventually freed, even if you forget to call dispose. But this is not always done, and even if it is done, the finalizer might not run immediately, and is not even guaranteed to run at all.

Comment: Following up on your first suggestion that some reference is being released after the exception, the obvious culprit was the GUI click handler and sure enough that is where the problem lies.